# Feature Reduction

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction

How do I reduce feature dimension ? My feature looks like :

1(Class Number) 10_10_1(File name)  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.564971751 23.16384181 25.98870056 19.20903955 16.10169492 13.27683616 1.694915254 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3.95480226  11.5819209  20.33898305 60.4519774  3.672316384 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3.107344633 62.99435028 33.89830508 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1.412429379 66.66666667 31.92090395 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.564971751 22.59887006 26.83615819 46.89265537 3.107344633 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.564971751 16.38418079 28.53107345 50.84745763 3.672316384 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   90.6779661  9.322033898 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.847457627 90.11299435 9.039548023 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17.79661017 81.3559322  0.847457627 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   27.11864407 72.88135593 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.564971751 37.85310734 61.29943503 0.282485876 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1.412429379 50.84745763 47.45762712 0.282485876 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   24.57627119 75.42372881 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17.23163842 82.20338983 0.564971751 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   29.37853107 70.62146893 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   55.64971751 44.35028249 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   64.40677966 35.59322034 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   67.79661017 32.20338983 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   66.66666667 33.33333333 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   3   2   6   7   5   4   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  14.81834463 3.818489078 3.292123621 2.219541777 2.740791003 1.160544518 2.820053602 1.006906813 0.090413195 2.246638594 0.269778302 2.183126126 2.239168249 0.781498607 2.229795302 0.743329919 1.293839141 0.783068011 1.104421291 0.770312707 0.697659061 1.082266169 0.408339745 1.073922207 0.999148017 0.602195061 1.247286588 0.712143548 0.867327913 0.603063537 0.474115683 0.596387106 0.370847522 0.54900076  0.35930586  0.580272233 0.397060362 0.535337691

After filename, feature values are given.

Comment: If you want to combine the features in order to reduce the number of features, then you can use a PCA. However, you may want to perform a feature selection (you select the best features and discard the other), then take a look to this course ( http://machinelearningmastery.com/an-introduction-to-feature-selection/ ). At the ends it points on three different libraries. Personally, I've only used Weka so far, and it's not really great for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If your feature is unsupervised, you can use [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)
PCA(copy=True, n_components=2, whiten=False)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

If it is supervised, you can use [LDA](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.lda import LDA
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
clf = LDA()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

For reducing the amount of features handed to models, besides others, feature reduction or feature deletion/selection can be used. Some frequently used **feature reduction** approaches have already been pointed out here, like principal component analysis (**PCA**), linear discriminant analysis (**LDA**), or partial least square regression (**PLSR**). Those essentially project the original data into a subspace, which aims for representing the information in less features. In particular, PCA thereby tries to maximize the preserved variance in the original data (unsupervised), while LDA tries to minimize intra-class-variance and maximize inter-class-distance (supervised, for classification), and PLSR tries to maximize the preserved variance in the original data and maximize the correlation with the target variable (supervised, regression).

Additionally, classic **feature selection** can be employed for reducing the amount of features. Those don't project data into a subspace but select "useful" features straight from the existing set of features. Usually those approaches are divided in **feature filters** and **feature wrappers**, where filters decide on which features to use by looking only at the features and the target variable (e.g. try to minimize inter-feature-correlation while maximizing the feature-target-correlation). In contrast, feature wrappers additionally consider the model that uses the selected features - so they directly optimize the model performance instead. Usually, filters are computationally cheaper than wrappers - but similar to using PCA, feature filters don't necessarily need to improve subsequent model performance, as they don't know *what* to optimize for.

Edit: as you are working with image data, feature filters and wrappers might not be optimal if used alone - they likely require image preprocessing and/or downsizing before being employed.

If you are using `R`, I'd recommend using the `caret` package, which provides all of the above already embedded into the model model training and evaluation process, which is quite important (cf. [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/featureselection.html) for some details on their filters/wrappers). Here's a small snippet for usage of the approaches above:

```
library(caret)
# PCA with preserving 95% variance in original data
modelPca <- train(x = iris[,1:4], iris[,5], preProcess=c('center', 'scale', 'pca'), trControl=trainControl(preProcOptions=list(thresh=0.95)),  method='svmLinear', tuneGrid=expand.grid(C=3**(-3:3)))
# LDA with selection of dimensions
modelLda2 <- train(x = iris[,1:4], y = iris[,5], method='lda2', tuneGrid=expand.grid(dimen=1:4))
# PLSR with selection of dimensions
modelPls <- train(x = iris[,1:3], y = iris[,4], method='pls', tuneGrid=expand.grid(ncomp=1:3))
# feature wrapper: (backwards) recursive feature elimination (there exist more...)
modelRfe <- rfe(x = iris[,1:4], y = iris[,5], sizes = 1:4, rfeControl = rfeControl())
# feature filter: univariate filtering
modelSbf <- sbf(x = iris[,1:4], y = iris[,5], sbfControl = sbfControl())
```